# Does Spotlight search work with a Time Capsule?

Tags: spotlight, time-capsule

I would like to use a Time Capsule as a file server for 3-4 Macs in a small network. 
I've 600 GB of data, and a lot of small files. My colleagues work a lot with Spotlight to find files. I would like to ask you: does Spotlight search work if I use a Time Capsule as a file server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes.

Per default, it will be indexed. You can opt-out any location in...

- **System Preferences → Spotlight → Privacy**

If you *add and remove* a location in the privacy tab, it will be re-indexed.

Also see Apple's support document **[Spotlight: How to re-index folders or volumes](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2409)**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I use this with Mac OS X 10.6.8 with a Time Capsule as an file server.
You must select "Shared" instead of "This Mac" in the Finder-Window.