# Searching for file within Time Capsule

Tags: macos, finder, time-machine, time-capsule

Mavericks OSX 10.9.5.
I need to locate a file in the Time Capsule.
I can navigate into the directory I want to search in, and using OSX find, I can "search" for a file that is right there and there are no results.

For example navigate to directory `Website` containing two or three files including `index.php` and search for "index.php" yields nothing.

I think that I'm not actually navigating to a directory, but that the OS is displaying a virtual directory based on the Time Capsule database.

How does one search for a file within Time Capsule backups?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Spotlight search work with a Time Capsule?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51896/does-spotlight-search-work-with-a-time-capsule)

Comment: I think it's not quite a duplicate because I would like other search options besides file name. This might belong in a separate post, but are `find | grep` searches possible in a mounted Time Capsule "drive"?

Comment: Seeing some possible approaches: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104570/how-to-search-mail-in-time-machine

Answer (score 1):

Searching a TimeMachine backup is tricky - for one thing Spotlight has not indexed the backup (do not tell Spotlight to do this - you will be in for a world of hurt)

Second, you are sort of correct about about TimeMachine being virtual.  what it really is a hundreds of symlinks that link about in all kinds of crazy ways.

Your best bet, is to mount the volume using TimeMachine and recover the file using the interface Apple has provided.

If you are not going to do that, then hopefully you know where the file should be on the original system, and you should navigate to `latest/path/to/file.html`  where "latest" is the name of one of the directories in at the root of the TimeMachine archive.  Really it is...  If you know what date you want the file from, you could use that date in place of "latest"

Comment: Drive was mounted. Issue is that in this case, I don't know *where* the file is. It's a LaTeX file so I tried searching by extension `.tex` and content `\documentclass`. Am I missing something in your answer that could help here?

Comment: Also is this: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716 what you're warning against as far as spotlight reindexing?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and did this:

You need to open a terminal: I use xquartz.

Go to the directory or network volume where you think the file is.

I did this on my mac:

cd /Volumes
cd OldDropboxArchive/

I needed to find a document about the standard model in particle physics. Which subdirectory could it be in? I know it's a word document. I type this:

find . -name "*particle*docx" -print

Hope this helps...